# html tags in the option tags

Tags: html, css

It seems an html tag can't be inserted in the option tag. Say

```
<option><em>somewords</em></option>
```

Is there other ways to style the "someword", without styling the option tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [It is bad to put <span /> tags inside <option /> tags, only for string manipulation not styling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styling the `<option>` is the only way. You can't even use `<span>` for styling.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all possible to have html tags inside `option` tag, Style `option` tag itself

```
option{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to do <option>this is **my** text</option>