# Selectbox: Using html elements in options values

Tags: html, css

Please see the picture

[image]

The Andrede option have red * , that is indicating mandatory field.

I've tried `Andrede<span class=required>*</span>` as option value , but its not working its showing the full html tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option elements can [contain only text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat).

If you want to include markup, then you need to replace the entire select element with a JavaScript widget.

I recommend changing the design so that you have a real `<label>` instead of using a placeholder or default value (both of which come with serious implications for accessibility). It is a webpage, so scrollbars are available. There is no need to have a cramped design.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking the given picture then they have their own select box which is build of elements other than option element