# different font sizes in <select> <option>

Tags: html

How do you have different font sizes in a selects option in HTML4

```
<option value="a">
<span style="font-size:8px; color:red;">A</span>
<span style="font-size:12px; color:blue;">B</span>
</option>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. [An option element can contain only text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat). Since you can't include elements, there is no way to differentiate parts of it for separate styling.