# Transfer class from clicked element to another

Tags: jquery, class, html-select

I am making a language selector — imagine a select tag with options in it.
Each option tag has a span with a unique class.

The thing I want to do is, to transfer that class to the select tag when clicked.

I don't have any code, so how is this done with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide the HTML code of that section?
You mean that there are `<span>` inside `<option>`?

That's not very good, see [It is bad to put <span /> tags inside <option /> tags, only for string manipulation not styling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat)

But now I just assume you want to copy the class of the `<option>` to the `<select>`

```
$('#selectid').change(function() {
  var target_class = $(this).find(':selected').attr('class');  
  $(this).removeClass().addClass(target_class);
  # removeClass to clear previous classes added
  # You could add back some default classes if you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$('select').change(function(){
   var t = $(this), o = t.find('option:selected span');
   t.addClass(o.attr('class'));
   o.removeClass();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default onload your span tag will be gone. With that being said I've made a brief broken down example for you [JsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vezEJ/)

. I recommend you work thru some css magic and continue the project. Here are some quick details.

```
<select>
    <option selected>select</option>
    <option class="a">1</option>
    <option class="b">2</option>
    <option class="c">3</option>
    <option class="d">4</option>
    <option class="e">5</option>
</select>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'select'){ 
            $(this).removeAttr('class')
        }else{
            $(this).find('option').each(function(){
                if($(this).text() == $(this).parent().val()){
                    $(this).parent().attr('class',$(this).attr('class'));
                }
            })
            alert($(this).attr('class')); // Select new class Value
        }
    })
})
</script>
```