# passing information of an item selected in a select tag to a table with mvc 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

this is my part of view:

1- the select tag content

```
<select name="select1" id="select1" class="nostyle" style="width: 100%;">
 <option></option>
  @{
    foreach (var item in Model)
   {                                        
       <option value=""> @Html.ActionLink(item.title, "getValIndicateurs", new { idIndicateur = @item.id_indicateur })</option>

                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
```

2-i can select an item, but the problem is that need to show the parameters of that item in this following table:

```
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">

                                @if (Session["listValeur"] != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (SIRE_Portail.Models.valeurs_indcateur item in (List<SIRE_Portail.Models.valeurs_indcateur>)Session["listValeur"])
                                    {

                                        <tr class="gradeA odd">
                           <td class=""></td>
                           <td class=""></td>
                           <td class=""></td>
                                        </tr>

                                    }
                                }
                                </tbody>
```

can anyone help !! thank you.

Comment: ActionLink inside an `<option>` element? I am not sure if this is valid HTML.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov You are correct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat

Comment: but it works i can see the items in the combo and i can select them using html5, well if you can suggest me another way to do it i'll be glad