# Strikeout few text in a select option

Tags: javascript, css, html, jsp

I have a requirement to strikeout second price value in the dropdown select list of options example : (32 $14.05 <strike>$100.00</strike>).
I am trying by adding some different class in a span for the second price but because to select option its removing the span. can anyone help how to get it done..?

```
<select data-theme="d" class="_variantOption" name="products[0].code">
    <option selected="selected">Select Size</option>
    <c:forEach var="option" items="${variant.variantOptions}" varStatus="st">
        <c:set var="disabled" value="${option.stockLevel < 1}" />
        <option value="${option.code}" ${(disabled) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : ''}>${option.qualifierValue}
            <format:markdownPrice priceData="${option.priceData}" markdownPriceData="${option.markdownPriceData}" />
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: post the related code here.. (if you don't want us to start from beginning).

Comment: <select data-theme="d" class="_variantOption" name="products[0].code">
 <option selected="selected">Select Size</option>
 <c:forEach var="option" items="${variant.variantOptions}" varStatus="st">
  <c:set var="disabled" value="${option.stockLevel < 1}" />
  <option 
   value="${option.code}" 
    ${(disabled) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : ''}
    >
    ${option.qualifierValue}
   <format:markdownPrice priceData="${option.priceData}" markdownPriceData="${option.markdownPriceData}" />
  </option>
  
 </c:forEach>
</select>

I am attaching the code , values are dynamic.

Comment: code inside <format:markdownPrice> :
<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${not empty markdownPriceData}">
  <h5><strong class="redfont">${markdownPriceData.formattedValue}</strong></h5>
  <span class="wasPrice">${priceData.formattedValue}</span>
 </c:when>
 <c:otherwise>
  <h5><strong>${priceData.formattedValue}</strong></h5>
 </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

Comment: You can't add html tags in option tag. check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5678760/1577396). IMO, try to create your own dropdown using `ul` and `li` tags if that feature is necessary.

Comment: You can't use elements inside an `option`, check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5678794/1930721

Comment: any way to get strikeout, any help?

Comment: I updated my above comment check..

Comment: @Mr_Green I got you point but If I go around to crete own dropdown using ul and li than I have to restart from the beginning. Lot of work.. Is there any other way around..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to strike out or otherwise format a part of an `option` element, since no tags are allowed inside the element. This isn’t just a theoretical rule: browsers actually ignore any markup that you try to use there.

You could inject HTML tags into `option` content, but this would work on some browsers only – Firefox, it seems (and could be regarded as something that shouldn’t work and will be fixed).

You could play with special characters, like U+0336 COMBINING LONG STROKE OVERLAY, and

```
<option>$14.05 $&#x336;1&#x336;0&#x336;0&#x336;.&#x336;0&#x336;0&#x336;
```

would work in a sense, provided that the font(s) used for `option` elements (which might be fixed in some browsers) contain(s) U+0336. The results are visually rather bad, but you can perhaps fix this with font settings like

```
select { font-family: Arial Unicode MS, Verdana }
```

On old browsers this probably fails one way or another, so I really suggest a different approach:

Replace the `select` element by a set of radio buttons. Then you can easily write

```
<input type=radio ...><label ...>$14.05 <s>$100.00</s></label>
```

Such a set won’t be a dropdown of course, but dropdowns are greatly overrated. Besides, you can turn it to a dropdown with some extra code if you really must.