# How can I have a tag inside of an option tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i'm trying to set:

```
jQuery('<select>').html('<option>aa<i class="test"></i></option>');
```

But i got

```
"<option>aa</option>"
```

So as you can see jquery strip tags inside  element.

Is any posibility to avoid this?

P.S. if I don't use js this work fine.

also this doesn't work too:

```
jQuery('<select>').html('<option>aa this is <strong>BOLD TEXT</strong></option>');
```

and this too:

```
jQuery('<select>').html('<option> aa<span class="a"></span></option>');
```

return only : " aa"

P.S.
as answered in
[It is bad to put <span /> tags inside <option /> tags, only for string manipulation not styling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat)

there is not a valid to put childs inside  tag.

Comment: My friend, a `<i>` tag inside of option is invalid html

Comment: "i" tag is used for example in font-awesome. and also you can try this wih any other tags <strong> for example

Comment: Just because font-awesome uses it, it does not make it valid. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option The `strong` tag is a different story from the `option` tag. Here is the what the link says "Permitted content: Text with eventually escaped characters (like &eacute;)."

Comment: Okay, ANY other tag (even <span>) also doesn't work, what I can do to avoid this?

Comment: You should not use any tags inside of an `option`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that an option tag cannot have any child elements.

Comment: jQuery('<select>').html('<option> aa<span class="a"></span></option>'); return only : "<option> aa</option>"

Comment: There is no need to provide 2 answers, just edit the answer you already have

Comment: But in plain html (without jquery). It will render good and work

Comment: Of course it will render if you put it in the plain markup but it is still invalid markup and should be avoided

Comment: So answer look like this is not allowed in specification, so it cannot have childs , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat