# Style part of an option in HTML choice list (<select>)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to style **only part** (word/letters) of a choice list option similar to this:

This is text containing `<span style="color:red;">Colored</span>` Text.

The example above works just fine. However if I try to do anything simmilar into `<select>` element, it doesn't render the **span** tag at all.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="alfaromeo"><span style="color:red">Alfa</span> Romeo</option>
</select>
```

Also you can specify style within the **option** tag, but this affects the whole choice, rather than a just part of it.

To sum it up, is there any good way to do this apart from making your own HTML element that looks like a **select**?

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/32hxtqfr/3/)

Comment: An option element cannot have any child elements.

Comment: "To sum it up, is there any good way to do this apart from making your own HTML element that looks like a select?" > To sum it up... NO :-)

Comment: What you can do is using a plugin that converts your `select` to a div or span based element. After that you can do this. Example of plugin: [selectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/index.html)

Comment: It's best to leave form elements as form elements, even if YOU think it isn't as pretty.  It ensures it can be used and recognized as a form across every device, reader, etc out there.

Comment: This article discusses this same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't style your `option` tags. You can use libraries like [Select 2](https://select2.github.io/) that hide your original `select` and create a new one, which can be stilized.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me.  Not sure how backwards compatible this code is with older browsers, but this was tested with Chrome.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    select.picker {
        font-size: 2.4em;
    }
    select.picker option {
        color: green;
    }
    select.picker option:first-child {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

and here is the markup

```
<select class="picker">
    <option value="a">Option A</option>
    <option value="b">Option B</option>
    <option value="c">Option C</option>
</select>
```

Evidence...

[image: select tag]

Happy Coding!

Comment: The OP wants only a part of the option styled not the entire text

Comment: gotcha. I didnt notice that when i first saw the question. I'll delete my response.

Answer (score 0):

Styling selects is a bore.  Try this option that mimics a select box with some CSS and jQuery:

https://github.com/octopuscreative/FancySelect