# How to get data of an element in selected option?

Tags: jquery, html

I have basic understand on jquery , but somehow I failed to get the data of an element in depth.

This is my HTML , which is a select box

```
<select id="from_acc">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Apple<span class="cr_info" data-value="1.00000" data-symbol="="></span></option>
<option value="1">Orange<span class="cr_info" data-value="2.00000" data-symbol="*"></span></option>
</select>
```

I am trying to find the **selected option** first and then get the element **span** which hold the data attribute.

Below is my current code , I expect to get a '=' in variable **string1** but this gave me a undefined value , Please advice

```
string1=$('#from_acc').find('option:selected').find('.cr_info').data('symbol');
alert(string1);
```

Comment: is span rendered inside option?

Comment: Yes , just an element to record the value I wanted

Comment: why not put the data attribute directly to option no need for span because i doubt that it is rendered

Comment: Somehow I am restricted due to previous design pattern that developed  by previous programmer , the span is rendered in google chrome , I have check the source page.

Comment: what version of it, in my chrome doesn't render

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat

Comment: [Can I use HTML tags in the options for select elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements). Even if we are giving it wont get rendered

Comment: I'm sorry , you were right , It wont render , I checked with ctrl+u in chrome but not with the inspection tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MDN, [`option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) elements can only contain text. In practice, it appears that browsers strip the `span` elements and their content.

Place the `data-` attributes on the `option` elements themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Drop down wont support span or any kind of tag in option, you can see it by inspect element it will not show span there, you can achieve this by adding `attribute` in `option`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#from_acc").change(function(){ 
        var symbol = $(this).find('option:selected').data('symbol');
        var value = $(this).find('option:selected').data('value'); 
        alert("symbol: "+ symbol +" value: "+ value )
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="from_acc">
<option value="1" selected="selected" data-symbol="=" data-value="1.00000">Apple</option>
<option value="1" data-symbol="*" data-value="2.00000">Orange</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A lot can be achieved with the use of the word 'this'. Expanding on how it is used would be helpful