# Angular 2 Dropdown option format part of the string

Tags: html, angular

We have a requirement where the dropdown option list has three parts.

1 - A code part like , 1 , 2 , 2c, 3, 3d etc.

2 - A company name part , like Columbia Water

3 - A color part, like Green, Orange etc.

I want to change the format of the text partially inside the string.

```
**2c**          Columbia Water             Green
```

I have tried this :-

```
<div>
<select> <!--[ngStyle]="{'color': 'black','font-size': '20px','font-weight': 'bold'}"-->
  <option>
  <li><font color="black"><b>2c</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Columbia Water&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font color="green">Green</font></li>
</option>        
</select>
```

If I put the ngStyle portion in the  tag, only the selected dropdown will be formatted , and that too the entire string.
The same goes for option, the entire string is formatted.
I tried putting **li** inside of option, but that does not do anything to the string itself.

Is this possible at all, this will be very useful as this will run on android as a hybrid cordova app.

Comment: I am using that as an example, we need it to be spaced out neatly, with the code part , tabbed , maybe twice, the company part and the color part.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `span` tag on each of the options and style appropriately in CSS.

```
    <span class='part-code'>2c</span> 
    <span class='company-name'>Columbia Water</span> 
    <span class='part-color'>Green</span>
```

Comment: Sir, Thank you. Let me try that. I also want to share with you, that the content ( strings ) come from an angular Array which has the three parts separated by a space. So I can manipulate the array elements and split them into these three span classes.

Comment: Sir, I tried it, it did not work inside of <option>. It does nothing to format the string. Also I found this stackoverflow link, can you please advise. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27514262/9016532 it details how to add style to options. I wasn't aware that option tags didn't pay attention to other tags within them.

Comment: Sir, Thank you, I will investigate , there is a fiddler as well to test it out.