# How to hide/show part of an option tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select tag with a number of options listed, and I have a button that should display more information to the user, including modifying the options to show more information. So, for example something like this:

**Normal View**

```
<option>RegularInfo</option>
```

**Extra View** - should be displayed after button click

```
<option>RegularInfo (ExtraInfo)</option>
```

I would like to have my button be able to toggle between these two views, but I'm not sure if there is a simple way to do it. One way I've considered is just writing a javascript function to modify the text manually, but then the code gets a bit messy with a lot of string manipulation.

I tried embedding a span with a class inside and then just toggling the class with jQuery like so:

```
<option>RegularInfo<span class = "extra">(ExtraInfo)</span></option>

//JQuery
$(".extra").toggle();
```

However, it turns out you cannot embed html elements inside an option tag, so this method didn't work for me.

Is there a way for me to toggle the visibility of *part* of an option without having to manually set the value of the option using javascript?

Comment: Generally no, since form elements are tricky one's when it comes to styling and behave quite different cross browsers

Comment: You could try to replace the whole content of the `<option>` tag, and see if that works: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2 (I haven't tried this myself, and you should test all relevant browsers) Alternatively you could add both options and `.show()` & `.hide()` them alternatively. I think that should work.

Comment: why can't you have both options in the list and render the options list based on the condition ?

Comment: Kiko Software, that's probably what i'll do if there really are no other ways of doing it, but the problem is I have multiple options with the info generated server side, so it could get a little more messy than just toggling the visibility of a class.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I should read better. So the answer to your question can only be: No, you can't.

Comment: @Keveloper, thanking on StackOverflow is done by upvoting and by answer accepting. If you are satisfied with my answer below, please mark it as accepted on the left side from the answer and / or upvote it. You will also get 2 points of reputation for answer accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can't nest child tags inside of `<option>` tags. If you don't want to append text with javascript, maybe try a method similar to this one of selecting text inside of your tags and manipulating it (in your case hiding and displaying it): https://stackoverflow.com/a/16585227/7184365

Answer (score 0):

I already did this in the past and you can just copy the codes here just alter it. But the definition here is you need to have a checkbox since checkbox only handles 2 values, on and off.. like a toggle button. You will just redesign the checkbox to a toggle button. But if your don't want to change the design, don't copy the css.

```js
<script>
     function clicker(enable){
      .. some codes here ..
     }
</script>
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
           <input type="checkbox" <?php echo "onclick='clicker("$someVar")'";
             if(!empty($someVar)){
                 echo " " . "checked";
             }
           ?>
           ><span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

and of course you need to save the event of the toggle button to the database so if you leave it, it will stay like that. So basically you will also need ajax for that.

Answer (score 0):

An option element cannot have any child elements.

From the HTML 5 draft spec:

> *Content model: Text.*

You can't nest child tags inside of `<option>` tags, but you can replace the text inside it.

**Replacing with pure JS:**

```js
function changeOptionText()
{
 var select1 = document.querySelector('#select1');
 select1.firstElementChild.innerHTML += ' (ExtraInfo)';
}
```

```html
<select id="select1">
 <option>RegularInfo</option>
 <option>Other info</option>
</select><br>
<input type="button" value="change option" onclick="changeOptionText()">
```

**Replacing with jQuery:**

```js
function changeOptionText()
{
 var firstOptEl = $('#select1 option').first();
 firstOptEl.html(firstOptEl.html() + ' (ExtraInfo)');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select1">
 <option>RegularInfo</option>
 <option>Other info</option>
</select><br>
<input type="button" value="change option" onclick="changeOptionText()">
```