# How can I add multiple elements like <span>, <p> or <div> inside <option> tag of <select> in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Reactjs is not allowing to add any html tags inside option tag. It only accepting one string enclosed by { }
I want to give some fixed width to the span.

Tried:-

```
1.    {<span>{country.iso_code}</span>
      <span>{country.dialing_code}</span>}

2.    <span>{country.iso_code}</span>
      <span>{country.dialing_code}</span>

3.    <Fragment><span>{country.iso_code}</span>
        <span>{country.dialing_code}</span></Fragment>
```

Code:-

```
    <select className={styles.selectCompany}
     name="country_code"
     value={this.state.personFields["country_code"]}
     onChange={this.handlePersonFieldsChange}>
     <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
     {
       this.props.countryList ?
       this.props.countryList.map((country, index) => {
       return (
         <option value={country.dialing_code} key={"code_" + index}>
          {country.iso_code +" +"+ country.dialing_code}
          //This is working line-i.e.only one string line
          {
            <span>{country.iso_code}</span>
            <span>{country.dialing_code}</span>
          }
         </option>
        )
      })
     : ''
     }
   </select>
```

I want to apply fixed width to the spans.

Comment: fixed width to span :(. why dont you try adding class to span ?

Comment: I tried that too, but <span> is not accepted by the option tag with or without class to span.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat

You need to use plugins or you can crete your own component to show select - options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the option value to fixed width, I guess we should trim/manipulate the string using JS, instead of the styling.

As you already noticed, the `<span>`is not allowed inside the option tag. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Comment: I want that the second <span> should start at fixed and proper position, so that all the records will be aligned properly irrespective of characters in first span. And the space in between them is managed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, could you add trailing space to iso code using Js， so that the following string can be aligned.