# innerHTML not showing contents of second <span> element in a <div>

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show the text within a `<span>` element inside a dropdown on mobile view. I can do this here in this jfiddle, but the application I have in progress (with the same logic) will NOT display the text within the second `<span>` of each `<div>` inside the #testing2 `<div>`.

Basically, Instead of seeing a dropdown menu with "first div first span (first div second span)" and "second div first span (second div second span)", the contents of the second `<span>` get cut out and all I see are the surrounding parantheses, like this: "first div first span ()" and "second div second span()".

Here is the example code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //create selcts
  var sel = $('<select id="testing3"/>');
  $("#testing2 div ").each(function() {
    sel.append(
      "<option>" + this.innerHTML + "</option>"
    );
  });
  $(".main_div").append(sel); //append in main div
  $("#testing3").hide() //hide it by default
  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    var $theWindowSize = $(this).width();
    if ($theWindowSize <= 700) {
      $("#testing3").show() //show or hide same
      $("#testing2").hide()
    } else if ($theWindowSize >= 701) {
      $("#testing3").hide()
      $("#testing2").show()
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_div">
  <div id="testing2">
    <div><span>first div first span (</span><span>first div second span</span>)</div>
    <div><span>second div first span (</span><span>second div second span</span>)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas as to why I can't see the contents of the second span in each div with two spans with this code?

Comment: You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to post the fiddle here instead of jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks, now people just need to please run the code snippet on full page view to see the responsiveness (not relevant to my question, however).

Comment: `<span>` inside `<option>` is invalid HTML.

Comment: When I run this in Chrome, the spans are removed and it just puts the text into the options.

Comment: Where is `#testing3` in the HTML?

Comment: Is there a way to view full page on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not valid to have `<span>` (or any other non-text nodes) inside `<option>`, see

[Is it bad to put <span /> tags inside <option /> tags, only for string manipulation not styling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat)

Change your code to use `this.textContent` instead of `this.innerHTML` so it just copies the text in the spans rather than the HTML tags.