# Pass JSX to <option></option> element in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I need to pass JSX to option element without getting this warnings:

```
Warning: Cannot infer the option value of complex children. Pass a `value` prop or use a plain string as children to <option>.

Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <p> cannot appear as a child of <option>.
```

It there a way to do it?

```
<div>
  <SelectBox onChange={handleChange} name="name" value={value}>
    <Option>
      <p className="text-red-500">ignacio</p>
    </Option>
    <Option>gustav</Option>
    <Option>benedikt</Option>
  </SelectBox>
</div>
```

SelectBox component:

```
const SelectBox: React.FC<React.SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>> = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <select {...rest}>
      <option value="" defaultChecked></option>
      {children}
    </select>
  );
};
```

Option component:

```
const Option: React.FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {
  return <option>{children}</option>;
};
```

Comment: Related Issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/is-it-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#technical_summary See "Permited Content".