# Highlight the text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one textbox, button and and list box with some text.

When I click on button what ever the text I enter in text if it matches the text in the list box I am trying to highlight that text using jquery I used this code.

Jquery Code

```
$("#btnhighlight").click(function () {
    alert("yes");
    var htext = $("#txthighlighttext").val();
    alert(htext);
    $("#lstCodelist").highlight('MD');
});
```

Style sheet I used to hightlight and i downloaded the highlight plug in added to the project

```
<style type="text/css">
    .highlight { background-color: yellow }
</style>
```

Please can any one help me out how to do this. or if I am doing wrong?
Can an

Comment: In your code you need to test if the `htext` value is `==` to a value in the list box. What does `#lstCodelist` look like?

Comment: that is select list <select id="lstCodelist" size="17" name="lstCodelist" style="width:100%;height:280px;background-color:#EFEFFB;"></select>

Comment: but are you using a particular plug-in?

Comment: I just downloaded this plug in http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your problem is that your script is executed before DOM ready.

try with this:

```
$(function (){
    $("#btnhighlight").click(function () {
        var htext = $("#txthighlighttext").text();
        $('#lstCodelist').highlight(htext);
    });
});
```

or put your script at the body end.

ps. I supposed you used this plugin ([jquery.highlight](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html))

edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/yJmBu/ here a full example

Comment: But still I am having same problem lisko, if I m put just the text in between the div tag its working but its not working for my select list.

Comment: it's weird, have you checked my jsfiddle link?

Comment: yes srilisko i check your, but the problem for my select list its not working when i insert some text in div and when i do this its working. is somehting differnt for my select list?

Comment: have you check the new link in my last comment? Could you try to copy and paste somewhere your code?

Comment: I did sirlisko, but no luck getting same problem its not working for my select its working for list box data and div data.

Comment: But i used a select too. Anyway try to paste all your code [here](http://pastebin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is generating spans around the text it finds. Option tags can not contain any html tags so the following (Generated by your plugin)

```
<select>
   <option><span class="highlight">Te</span>st</option>
</select>
```

is illegal syntax and will be ignored by the browser.

However if I understand your intent, there are some plugins out there that will accomplish something similar for you out of the box.

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

Some proof that a nested span inside an option is not allowed.

- [html tags in the option tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058554/html-tags-in-the-option-tags)
- [It is bad to put <span /> tags inside <option /> tags, only for string manipulation not styling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulati)

Comment: Yes if I do the text in div tag my highlight is working for my text is in between  <select id="lstCodelist" size="17" name="lstCodelist" style="width:100%;height:280px;background-color:#EFEFFB;"> <option><span class="highlight">Te</span>st</option></select>
                
                    Selected text:<div id="ddTitle2" class="ddTitle">&nbsp;</div> its not working for me.

Comment: Correct, So we can conclude that you need to approach the problem in a different way (without using the `<select><option>` tags). I would suggest generating the list as a table or group of divs since they **can** contain other html tags within them. The above link provides an excellent example of this.